# GDB 6.3 gives "Cannot access memory at address 0x<32bitval>" when stepping through code

Tags: debugging, memory, gdb

I'm using the gdb debugger to step through my code to verify my logic for sample inputs, but I'm getting this error whenever i'm trying to read the value of any variable/structure/STL object (using print). However, when I'm printing the contents of the address (which gdb allegedly cannot access), I'm reading back the value properly. Any ideas whats going wroing ?

Sample session:

`(gdb) p xtalFreq

Cannot access memory at address 0xffd3dd38

(gdb) p *0xffd3dd38

$9 = 27000`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the answer - this was a bug in GDB 6.3 itself, which got fixed in the latest version (GDB 7.1)